# Is it possible to make type safe Java Collections whose members merely implement several interfaces?

Tags: java, generics

If I have:

```
interface A{  void a();  }
interface B{  void b();  }
```

I can hava a generic method like this:

```
class C {
    <T extends A & B> void c(T t) {
        t.a();
        t.b();
    }
}
```

But i can't hava a generic collection like this:

```
class D{
    List<? extends A & B> l;
}
```

I know that I could make an empty interface E that extends both A and B, and have a List that contains E's...  but I'd rather leave my classes marked with just A and B, and not have to have an E.  This is even more problematic when there are many more A's and B's that can be combined in 2^n ways.

I would rather be able to define a type on the fly, as a union of interfaces, and have the collections recognize objects that implement all of the interfaces as instances of that type.

Is there a way to do this in Java?  I'm open to any kind of work around or hack at this point in order to avoid making a new interface, and tagging my classes with it, just so that they can live together in a collection.  Or, if someone could clarify for me why this is impossible, that would be equally appreciated.

Comment: You mean and *intersection* of interfaces, don't you?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I mean a union of interfaces.  You're probably thinking of how there is a different (hopefully not disjoint) set of classes that implement each interface.  Then the set of classes that implements the union of the interfaces is the intersection of the sets described above.

Answer (score 9):

```
public class Foo<T extends A & B> {
    private List<T> list;
    //getters, setters, etc.
}
```

Comment: (This now allows `Foo<?> l;` in `D`.)

Comment: I see that `Foo<?>` can be declared in `D`, but not how to instantiate it...  I should add that I modified the question so that the solution should be type safe.  Otherwise, this could be done with raw `List`s from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

As Jeffrey also said somehow, you have to parameterize your class `D`:

```
class D<T extends A & B> {
    List<T> l;

    /**
     * this is just a method for the sake of example
     */
    public T getSomeMember() {
        return l.iterator().next();
    }
}
```

This way you are deferring your choice of the actual type `T` to the method which actually insntatiates `D`. If that information is not available even at that point you will have to parameterize that method too with `<T extends A & B>`:

```
private <T extends A & B>
void doSomething() {
    D<T> d = new D<T>();

    T v1 = d.getSomeMember();
    A v2 = d.getSomeMember();
    B v3 = d.getSomeMember();
}
```

If there is a field of type `D` in some class, then that class must know the actual type that `extends A & B`, or be itself parameterized if it doesn't. In principle you propagate the type parameter up until you know the actual type.

Be warned that this process is likely to become unmanageable for large codes. It may also result in ugly code, but of course that depend on your conception of aesthetics.

Comment: The whole point is that I want to avoid having a type `T` (which would be the interface `E` from the original question).  I would like to allow anything that implements both `A & B` into the collection, and nothing that doesn't implement both.  I don't want to require members of the collection to have anything in common except that they both implement `A & B`.  (Or the reason this is impossible...)